# Adding css class to Symfony2 form itself

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Some code first:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) {

            /** @var Company $company */
            $company = $event->getData();
            $form    = $event->getForm();

            $form->add(
                'paymentTerms',
                'integer',
                array(
                    'label'          => 'Payment Terms',
                    'label_attr'     => array(
                        'class' => 'col-sm-4 control-label'
                    ),
                    'attr'           => array(
                        'class' => 'form-control'
                    ),
                    'error_bubbling' => true
                )
            );
        }
    )->setAction('test action')->setAttributes(array('class' => 'form-horizontal'));
}
```

Can someone explain why I can't seem to be able to add a css class to the form itself?

In the above example `->setAction('test action')` works perfectly fine, but `->setAttributes(array('class' => 'form-horizontal'))` doesn't have any effect on the form.

I've tried `->setAttribute('class', 'form-horizontal')` as well with no luck. No errors, it's as if it's being ignored. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `attr` definition to your defaults like you normally would to any field:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        ...
        'attr'       => array(
            'class' => 'form-horizontal'
        ),
    ));
}
```

Anyway, it's best practice to limit style definition to your views. You should add the `class` attribute to your form like this ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-each-field-by-hand)):

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal' }}) }}
```